# How to simulate click on <div role="button">?

Tags: javascript, dom, events, methods

I have an element on a web page.

```
<div class="profile-action profile-action--lg profile-action--color-yes profile-action--filled   js-profile-header-vote-yes js-profile-header-vote" data-choice="yes" role="button">                
    <div class="profile-action__icon">                    
        <i class="icon icon--stretch">                        
            <svg class="icon__svg">                             
                <use xlink:href="#floating-action-yes"></use>                                                     
            </svg>  
        </i>                
    </div>            
</div>
```

I am trying to simulate a click event by below code.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("js-profile-header-vote-yes")[0].click()
```

It doesnt simulate any clicks on that element. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:I have tried jQuery and dispatchEvent, they dont work either. I have tried selenium as well, it works but this is not what I want.

Edit2: I dont want to handle a click event, I want to simulate a click method.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("js-profile-header-vote-yes")[0].click(), note the "s" in getElements

Comment: start with [Creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Comment: @ashu sorry, thats actually what I am doing, it highlights the element when I write the code in the console, so I dont think I have a problem selecting the right element, I just made a mistake on my code here.

Comment: @NikosM. I have tried dispatchEvent(new mouseEvent("click")), it wont work either.

Comment: Maybe the event handler listens on an event other than `click`, such as `mousedown`, or it's listening on something other than the `div`, like the `svg`. You can use the devtools to analyze which elements have a listener attached to which events.

Comment: @CherryDT That what I was thinking but I dont know where to start or how to see the actual event that the event handler listens in devtools.

Comment: You haven't indicated what you expect to happen on click.

Comment: @pilchard I click that div button on the webpage and it likes the person. I am trying to automate a badoo auto liker.

Answer (score 3):

[`.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) works just fine, but unless there is an [eventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) attached to the element nothing will occur.

I would also avoid using [`document.getElementsByClassname()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) unless you specifically need a live [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). [`document.querySelector('.classname')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) is more appropriate here and returns a static [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which is more predictable as it doesn't update with the DOM.

```js
const buttonDiv = document.querySelector('.js-profile-header-vote-yes');

buttonDiv.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('clicked'));

buttonDiv.click();
```

```html
<div class="profile-action profile-action--lg profile-action--color-yes profile-action--filled   js-profile-header-vote-yes js-profile-header-vote" data-choice="yes" role="button">                
    <div class="profile-action__icon">                    
        <i class="icon icon--stretch">                        
            <svg class="icon__svg">                             
                <use xlink:href="#floating-action-yes"></use>                                                     
            </svg>  
        </i>                
    </div>            
</div>
```

Comment: So "buttonDiv.click();" logs "clicked" in the console, but doesnt actually click the element. Why?

Comment: ? what do you mean doesn't click the element? as per the docs > `The HTMLElement.click() method simulates a mouse click on an element.` < meaning it fires all 'click' listeners attached to the element. If you want to affect visuals you need to account for this in the listener callback.

Comment: I am guessing it simulates the click method but the div button actually listens another event because what happens after I manually click the button doesnt happen with my elem.click() method.

Comment: Without more information about what you expect it to do there isn't much else to add. You can check the attached listeners in the developer console.

Comment: Thats what I need to do I guess, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The **modern way** to simulate synthetic events (both built-in and custom) as provided by [MDN's Creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#Triggering_built-in_events)

```
function simulateMouseEVent(type, elem) {
  elem.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(type, {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
  }));
  return elem; // make it chainable
}
```

How to use:

```
simulateMouseEVent('click', document.getElementsByClassName("js-profile-header-vote-yes")[0]);
```

Comment: Doesnt it do the same thing that elem.click() does?

Comment: `click()` is a standard method of an `HTMLElement` and supported by all browsers.

Comment: @pilchard I meant backwards compatiblity including IE

Comment: [Supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click#Browser_compatibility) by IE all the way back to 5.5.

Comment: @pilchard, oh I got confused over `dispatchEvent` method for IE. Thanks for the reminder

Comment: No worries, it's a good method to know about, just made redundant by click() in this case.